# How to align git working copy using only Android Studio git plugin GUI

Tags: android-studio, testing, github, intellij-idea, version-control

There are a bunch of decade-old answers for using git command line to accomplish various goals, but this question is how to use the standard git plugin for Android Studio 3.3.1, **GUI only** to "fix" a common "problem".  Maybe it's "impossible" without git command line.  If so, then that's the answer: "impossible", but you would have to wonder about the authors of the VSC plug-in.

## Scenario

You would like to test some code that's hosted on github.com and you only want to use the GUI of Android Studio.  You're asked to test but don't know how to switch branches and keep an exact match with the code you're supposed to be testing.  You have read-only access to the remotes.

#### Checkout / Clone

Within Android Studio, you select `VCS > Checkout from Version Control > Git`, then you paste the url you found while using your web browser.  So it might be something like `https://github.com/someguy42/someproggy42`.  You hit the test button and it says *Connection successful*.  Then you hit the **Clone** button.

You check the remotes: `VCS > Git > Remotes...` If the one you want isn't there, you do`(plus sign) > (url of repository found in github.com)`.  You specify the name of this remote as `someguy42`.

You then do a fetch `VCS > Git > Fetch`.  At the bottom right of the Android studio, you click and you see `someguy42\master`, `someguy42\feature1`, `someguy42\feature2`.  You note on the web that both features branched off from master.

All is well.  So far.

#### Testing Two Branches

You are asked to test both features.

So from the list you see by left clicking on the bottom right of the IDE, you right click on `someguy42\feature1 > Checkout As... > feature1`.

You complete your work on feature 1.  Maybe you add a logging statement or something, but nothing you care to save.

Now it's time for feature 2, so you repeat the process as before: from list on the bottom right of the IDE, you right click on `someguy42\feature2 > Checkout As... > feature2`.

You notice something odd.  You now have a **mixture of feature1 and feature2 in your IDE!**

You prove this to yourself by going to the Android `app` folder, right click and select `Git > Compare with Branch...` and you compare with the remote `someguy42\master`.  You expect to see only files changed in feature2, **but both feature1 and feature2 files are in the list**.

#### Question

What steps, *executed exclusively through the Android Studio GUI and the VCS plug-in*, would make it so your working copy was a guaranteed pristine copy of only files from feature2?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Android Studio user, but I use Intellij Ultimate, and **the behavior you are experiencing is not the expected one**.

---

If I checkout `feature1`, change nothing, and then I checkout `feature2`, my working copy becomes exactly `feature2` -- nothing from `feature1` that wasn't also in `feature2` should be there. That's how it's supposed to work.

If I, however, modified some files while in `feature1` and then checked out `feature2` (without committing said changes first), my working copy would become a mix of `feature2` *and the uncommited changes I made* while on `feature1` -- changes that may or may not contain code from `feature1` itself.

Example given: if `feature1` introduced a new parameter `newParam1`, and for testing purposes *I* introduced a log line like this:

```
private doSomething(String oldParam, String newParam1) { // feature1 change
    logger.debug("newParam1="+newParam1); // my own uncommited change
    //...
```

And then, *without committing that line*, I switched to `feature2` which introduced a new-but-different `newParam2`, I would end up with this:

```
private doSomething(String oldParam, String newParam2) { // feature2 change
    logger.debug("newParam1="+newParam1); // my own uncommited change
    //...
```

That's how it's supposed to work.
If that is what you're experiencing, that's OK -- just rollback (Ctrl+Alt+Z) or Shelve (Ctrl+Alt+H) your own uncommited changes before checking out other branches, to make sure that your workspace is clean.

**If the above is *not* what you're experiencing, it may be a bug**. I'd delete my local copies of the branches, check them out again and, if the same thing happened again, file a bug at [YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com).

---

PS: It may also be the case that `feature2` cherry-picked the changes from `feature1`, despite both branches stemming out from `master`. If that were the case, then it'd be OK for those changes to be on `feature2` too. You may inspect the commit log for `feature2` using *Version Control* (Alt+9) *→ Log* (maybe filtering by *Branch:`feature2`*) to check if that's the case.

Comment: I'm coming to the conclusion that there was something else going on with local changes.  I think key to keeping things from getting out of line is to always revert local changes before changing branches.

Comment: @Dale That was exactly my answer: _"working copy would become a mix of feature2 and the uncommited changes [...] just rollback (Ctrl+Alt+Z) or Shelve (Ctrl+Alt+H) your own uncommited changes before checking out other branches"_. And yet you didn't award the bounty, accept or event upvote the answer.

Comment: I've been on another project and haven't made the effort to get back into this problem enough.